# Compare list in a dataframe with another list, and if not found then save it in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to ask, for example I have a list of vocabulary and a dataframe. The dataframe contains tokenized sentences.

```
vocab_list = ['aaa',....,'zzz']
```

Dataframe

```
tokenized_sentenced
========
[lorem , ipsum]
[it , is, a, long, established, fact ]
[various, versions, have, evolved]
[the, generated, lorem, ipsum]
```

How to store the list of the token that is not found in the vocabulary list into a new column in the dataframe. The result should be like this:

```
   tokenized_sentenced                        token_not_found_in_vocab
    =========================================|===========================
    [lorem , ipsum]                          |[lorem, ipsum]
    [it , is, a, long, established, fact ]   |[]
    [various, versions, have, evolved, toq]  |[toq]
    [the, generated, lorem, ipsum]           |[lorem, ipsum]
```

i tried this:

```
for i in range(0,1005):
  for j in range(0, len(df['tokenized_sentenced'][i])-1):
    if (df['tokenized_sentenced'][i][j] not in vocab_list):
      
      df['token_not_found_in_vocab'][i].append(df['tokenized_sentenced'][i][j])
```

but i got error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following can solve your problem in one line:

```
df['token_not_found_in_vocab'] = df['tokenized_sentenced'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x).difference(vocab_list)))
```